# ebean in play 2 framework with SQL dialect

Tags: sql, playframework-2.0, teradata, ebean, dialect

I'm trying to establish friendship between Teradata 13.10 and play 2 framework using ebean ORM layer. My app does try to query DB:

```
 select t0.workflow_id c0, t0.CHNL_TYPE_CD c1, t0.WORKFLOW_NAME c2, t0.INFO_SYSTEM_TYPE_CD c3, t0.FOLDER_NAME c4 from ETL_WORKFLOW t0 order by name limit 11
```

The problem is... that Teradata does know nothing about **LIMIT** Is there any possibility to find implementation/override something and make underlying ORM work with Teradata?

UPD:
Seems like I have to do something with tese classes:
http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/index.html
I'm looking for samples:
1. Set proper SQL dialect for ebean or make it work in SQL ANSI mode.
2. Override classes for ebean and write own implementation of LIMIT functionality.

Comment: Have you tried using SELECT TOP 11 ?

Comment: I'm using such construction: return find.orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
           .findPagingList(pageSize)
           .getPage(page);
and it does generate a query mentioned in a question. I'm looking for a way to stop EBEAN using "special" LIMIT and use someting more general.

Comment: get the latest version of ebean.jar now its 2.7.7
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ebeanorm/files/

Answer (score 0):

Teradata supports both the `TOP n` operator and `SAMPLE` clause in your `SELECT` statement. `TOP n` being an extension to the ANSI SQL 2008 standard is the closest equivalent to the `LIMIT n` operator you are looking for.

`TOP n` is processed after all the other clauses in your `SELECT` statement have been satisfied. It is the functional replacement of using the `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER()` or `QUALIFY RANK()` window aggregates to accomplish the same task providing at worst equivalent performance of the window aggregate functions.

`SAMPLE` provides you some additional flexibility by allowing you to returned multiple sample sets within a single result. It can also be used for simple, random samples from a resultset as well. Given the options that are available with `SAMPLE` you are best served with referring to the SQL Data Manipulation Language manual for Teradata for all of the details. The Teradata  manuals can be downloaded from [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/Datawarehouse/eBrowseBy.cfm?page=TeradataDatabase). Just select which version of Teradata you wish to download the manuals for.

**Edit:**
Using the [RawSQL](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_rawsql.html) feature with Ebean you may be able use either the `SAMPLE` or `TOP n` operators in your SQL explicitly and not allow Ebean to add expressions such as the LIMIT OFFSET clause automatically. Have you tried this approach yet?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Rob. Seems like I didn't correctly explain what I need. Now I'm using play2 with JPA+TeradataDialect. I would like to find a way to shitch to ebean ORM implementation with Teradata dialect/ANSI support. Now it doesn't work out of the box. By default ebean produces SQL queries that are not valid for Teradata DB.